# How can I add a custom input accessory view containing a UITextField that is invoked from a UIButton press?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, inputaccessoryview

Most situations require the custom input accessory view from a xib to be invoked when a UITextField or UITextView becomes first responder. Although, I need the custom input accessory view to be presented above the keyboard whenever a UIButton is pressed.

I've tried many things, such as allowing the view to become first responder, which does in fact present the custom input accessory view from my xib, but the keyboard does not appear along with it.

The best example as to what I'm trying to accomplish is exactly the same behavior as pressing the "Find on Page" button in the activity menu of iOS Safari.app.

I can provide code samples if anyone would like to view my progress and attempts. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardBarViewController : UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {

        self.view = KeyboardView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func previousPressed() {

        print( "PREV" )
    }

    @IBAction func nextPressed() {

        print( "NEXT" )
    }


    @IBAction func donePressed() {

        print( "DONE" )
    }

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
}



import UIKit

class KeyboardView : UIView {

    var keyboardBar = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed( "KeyboardBar", owner: nil, options: nil).last?.view as! KeyboardBar

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {

        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView : KeyboardBar {

        return keyboardBar
    }
}


import UIKit

class KeyboardBar : UIView {

   // stubbed out to be used as a class type for casting the xib contents
}
```

Comment: Have you set the canBecomeFirstResponder to YES??

Comment: Yes, here's my code pertaining to my issue: